# Performance issue on parsing JSON and storing data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, algorithm, neo4j

I am trying to build a web app that converts sketches to slides. The location and category of objects on a slide will be given by a JSON like below:

```
[
  {
    "attachment": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some_picture.jpg",
    "response": {
      "annotations": [
        {
          "width": 72,
          "height": 20,
          "left": 24,
          "top": 180,
          "label": "text"
        },
        {
          "width": 96,
          "height": 19,
          "left": 26,
          "top": 212,
          "label": "picture"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I used an each loop to go through the objects in the JSON file and then store them to a Neo4j database.

```
def save_detection_to_db(detection_json)
  detection_json.each do |single_picture|
    annotations = single_picture["response"]["annotations"]
    annotations.each do |single_annotation|
      label = single_annotation["label"]
      determine_node_label(label).create(width: single_annotation["width"], 
                                         height: single_annotation["height"],
                                         top: single_annotation["top"],
                                         left: single_annotation["left"],
                                         category: single_annotation["label"])
    end
  end
end

# determine_node_label("text") #=> Text
# determine_node_label("picture") #=> Picture
```

This way I can store around 100 objects in 0.6s. But given that this app is designed to be used by many people to generate slides, it won’t do the job. I am assuming the each loop is not a good way to do it. What other methods should I try? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
def save_detection_to_db(detection_json)
  detection_json.each do |single_picture|
    annotations = single_picture["response"]["annotations"].group_by{|x| x["label"]}
    annotations.each do |k, values|
      klass = determine_node_label(k)
      values.each do |value|
         value["category"] = value.delete("label")
         klass.create(value)
      end 
    end
end
```

In the above code, we are not finding the node for each records, the group_by will group the nodes and finding for them only, it will reduce more looping thing and also each val.

I don't have any knowledge on neo4jr, if you have any batch inserts in neo4j just take the values and insert from there.

```
value["category"] = value.delete("label")
```

means:

In the loop we will have a value is:

```
{"width"=>72, "height"=>20, "left"=>24, "top"=>180, "label"=>"text"}
```

in DB we have "category" attribute, we don't have "label", that's the reason, I am replacing a "label" key with "Category" using by the code snippet.

Comment: This is very helpful! But could you explain `value["category"] = value.delete("label")`?

Comment: value["category"] = value.delete("label")
means:

In the loop we will have a value is:

    {"width"=>72, "height"=>20, "left"=>24, "top"=>180, "label"=>"text"}


in DB we have "category" attribute, we don't have "label", that's the reason, I am replacing a "label" key with "Category" using by the code snippet.
Same explanation updated in post.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a [batch insert](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Batch-insert) into neo4j. There are a number of examples on how to do it [here](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/batch_insert).